# Consuming proteins only after training?

Tags: protein, calisthenics

I have been doing calisthenics for more than one year, with strength and body shape results much appreciated by myself. However, in the last few months, my body hasn't changed much, which I can probably understand, since I haven't taken any product like protein whey and stuff like that. I was wondering if using the 90% protein whey after training only, as I am doing now, is somehow a good choice or not in terms of gaining more muscle mass.

Comment: If you're not gaining muscle and you're fairly sure your training is on point, then chances are you're simply not consuming enough calories. Protein powder isn't a magical powder that will immediately lean to gainz, most protein powders are actually crap disguised as a suppliment. Much better to try to eat more as part of your regular meals and see if that helps.

Comment: +1 to @DarkHippo. No really lots of pros for gaining in using protein powder - protein from consumed food is ok too (well, this powder actually they get as byproduct from, as example, milk products production). Only if you want to consume your dose of protein fast. But it would cost you twice or three times more

Comment: [crosspost](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/14179/527)

Comment: Agree with @DarkHippo. In reality, most people don't actually **need** protein powder (unless you're a hardcore bodybuilder or athlete), it's usually all in a proper diet. Adding more protein to your diet as needed. Just remember, protein can become fat just as easily as any other food when consumed in excess, so don't assume "because it's protein it won't make me fat".

Comment: Yes sir I agree that excess is wrong choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supplemented protein should ideally be only a small part of your total daily protein intake. There are sources of very good proteins (depending on your diet).

- Dairy (such as (lowfat) quark, cottage cheese and the like)
- Eggs
- Lean meat
- Soy Beans
- ...

The ballpark is something around 2 grams of protein per kg bodyweight to gain muscles. Assuming a weight of 80 kg that would be roundabout 160 g. You could reach this (for example) whith

- 50g 90% Whey
- 300 g chicken breast
- 300 g cottage cheese
- Two eggs

(only a rough estimate, just to give you an idea). This is not considering that other foods contain proteins, too.

**EDIT:**

2 g per kg bodyweight seems to be too much. See [this article](https://bayesianbodybuilding.com/the-myth-of-1glb-optimal-protein-intake-for-bodybuilders/).

Comment: Yes sir, I consume 25 g of protein whey on 250 mL of milk, and I'm sure it is a quality product for both the production location and the quality marks, reliable ones, in fact it's very expensive, about 50 euros for 750g. I've only started yesterday though so was willing to make this question. To answer the comment right up, I gained muscle mass of course throughout all this training, just I'd like more of it, but not too much more.